What is API endpoint for Google Search Results Page
There is private autocomplete endpoint:
https://wwww.google.com/complete/search?q=term&client=chrome 
And I wonder how does google get its SERP results?
I inspected HTTP requests through Dev Tools and I suspect google obfuscate HTTP requests for that endpoint or is SERP results might be plain HTML response and not JSON one?

Why would you expect there to be a JSON endpoint?
